# Limit labels in bubble plot using Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I plotted [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_TcNEgb75M3W6K_B3dE7g_5d0O9bRXh/view?usp=sharing) using the following code:

```
fig, (ax) = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(12,8))
ax.scatter(x=df['GDP(PPP) per capita'], 
           y=df['Energy use'], 
           s=df['Population']/100000, 
           alpha=0.4,
           c=np.arange(132), 
           cmap='tab10',  
           edgecolors="gray", 
           linewidth=0.2)

# Bubble labels
x,y = df['GDP(PPP) per capita'], df['Energy use']
for i, txt in enumerate(df['Country Name']):
    plt.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]))
    print(i, txt, x[i], y[i], df['Population'][i], df['Bubble color'][i])

plt.show()
```

This is the result:
[image]

As you can see, the labels are overlapped and difficult to read.
I want to limit which labels to be shown, i.e. only the countries of my choice from column 'Country Name' in the dataframe. How to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: You can put the countries of your choice in a list and do a check before calling `plt.annotate` on each point.

Comment: @SIA. I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: you may also look at this package https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to filter `Country Name` values

```
chosen_countries = ['Norway', 'Canada'] # fill in the list with countries of your choice

x,y = df['GDP(PPP) per capita'], df['Energy use']
for i, txt in enumerate(df['Country Name']):
    if txt in chosen_countries:
        plt.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]))
        print(i, txt, x[i], y[i], df['Population'][i], df['Bubble color'][i])

plt.show()
```